# How to Mock the return object

Tags: c++, unit-testing, googletest, googlemock

I try to mock a User class and its nested struct UserBuilder:

```
class User
{
  public:
        virtual int loadData(const std::string& filename);
        virtual UserBuilder getUserBuilder(const std::string& functionName) const;

        struct UserBuilder
       {
        UserBuilder(std::string functionName) : m_functionName{functionName} {};
        virtual ~UserBuilder();
        virtual UserBuilder& fun1();
        virtual UserBuilder& fun2(int32_t num);
        virtual bool callFunction();
       private:
        std::string m_functionName{};
      };
}
```

This is the mock class for User:

```
class UserMock : public User
{
public:
    MOCK_METHOD1(loadData, int(const std::string& filename));
    MOCK_CONST_METHOD1(getUserBuilder, UserBuilder(const std::string& functionName));
};
```

Thsi is the mock class for UserBuilder:

```
struct UserBuilderMock : public User::UserBuilder
{
public:
    UserBuilderMock(std::string functionName) : User::UserBuilder(functionName) {}
    MOCK_METHOD0(fun1, UserBuilder&());
    MOCK_METHOD1(fun2, UserBuilder&(int32_t num));
    MOCK_METHOD0(callFunction, bool());
};
```

I want to test this function:

```
void useCase(std::unique_ptr<User> userP)
{   
    int status = userP->loadFile("init");
    if (status == 0)
    {
        User::UserBuilder builder = userP->getUserlBuilder("init");
        bool result = builder.fun1().fun2(1).callFunction();
        return result;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

I give the getUserBuilder("init") a mock object builderMock as its return value, like this:

```
auto userMock = std::make_unique<UserMock>();
ON_CALL(*userMock, loadFile("init")).WillByDefault(Return(0));
UserBuilderMock builderMock("init");
EXPECT_CALL(*userMock, getUserBuilder("init")).WillOnce(ReturnPointee(&builderMock));
EXPECT_CALL(builderMock,fun1()).Times(1);
```

The test log fail: fun1 never called-unsatisfied and active.
I want to use the builderMock object to call the mock method fun1,fun2 and callFunction, but it still use the real UserBuilder object
call the real fun1,fun2 and callFunction. What should I do to make it use Mock object call the Mock method?

Comment: `virtual UserBuilder getUserBuilder(const std::string& functionName) const;` is not returning pointer

Comment: If I change that return value to: virtual std:unique_ptr<UserBuilder> , how should I give the MOCK method getUserBuilder() return value, I try Return(ByRef(builderMockP), builderMockP is a unique_ptr<UserBuilderMock>, it does not work

Answer (score 1):

You have to rewrite your code to make User::getUserBuilder return a pointer (possibly smart one) to UserBuilder.

With the method returning UserBuilder object

```
EXPECT_CALL(*userMock, getUserBuilder("init")).WillOnce(ReturnPointee(&builderMock));
```

getUserBuilder casts the mock to an object of its base class (slicing), losing all the the mock additions.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. If we can not change the User::getUserBuilder return type, do you think is there any way we can test the fun1,fun2 and callFunction.

Comment: Does User/UserBuilder come from some library that you cannot change?

Comment: Yes, it comes from a library, not easy for me to change it.

Comment: if I change the virtual UserBuilder getUserBuilder(const std::string& functionName) const; to virtual std::unique_ptr<User::UserBuilder> getUserBuilder(const std::string& functionName) const; do you think what value I should give as the return value for mock method getUserBuilder(), still ReturnPointee(&builderMock) or not?

Comment: Just return std::unique_ptr<User::UserBuilder>. Have the mock object allocated using unque_ptr and then
Return(ByMove(uniquePointerToMock))

Comment: If I do it like: User::UserBuilder* builderP=new BuilderMock("init"); EXPECT_CALL(*userMock, getUserBuilder("init")).WillOnce(Return(ByMove(std::unique_prt<User::UserBuilder>builderP)); then EXPECT_CALL(*builderP, fun1()).Times(1); but it still fail, did not call the UserBuildeMock fun1(), still call the real UserBuilder fun1(). Because if I comment the EXPECT_CALL(*builderP, fun1()).Times(1), run the test, the test log output a trace in the real User::UserBuilder::callfunction()