# how to mock a return value which type is std::unique_ptr

Tags: c++, unit-testing, smart-pointers, googletest, googlemock

I have a Mock method:

```
MOCK_METHOD1(start, std::unique_ptr<SomeStruct>(const std::string& name));
```

I mock SomeStruct as SomeStructMock:

```
struct SomeStructMock : public SomeStruct
{
 ...
}
```

I also want to set some expectation on SomeStructMock object. I try to give a return value
to the mock method start, by

```
Return(ByMove(std::make_unique<SomeStructMock>())
```

but it looks like the
return pointer still point to a real SomeStruct, not SomeStructMock object, what is the problem?

Comment: if I do like this: builderP = std::make_unique<SomeStructMock>(); give the mock method return value like this: Return(ByMove(builderP)), got this error:  use of deleted function ‘std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>::unique_ptr(const std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>&)

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: "*it looks like the return pointer still point to a real SomeStruct, not SomeStructMock object*"... You'd probably have the exact same problem if you returned a raw pointer, too. Read [this](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googlemock/docs/cook_book.md#mocking-non-virtual-methods-mockingnonvirtualmethods).

Comment: The example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59983087/how-to-mock-the-return-object, I just change virtual UserBuilder getUserBuilder(const std::string& functionName) const; to virtual std::unique_ptr<UserBuilder> getUserBuilder(const std::string& functionName) const